# NoneType-Error with yield in Python

Tags: python, iteration, yield, nonetype

I've got a problem with the yield and generator thing in Python, hope you might know the solution

Here's my code (very simplified)

```
!/usr/bin/env

import sys
import time
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *
import numpy
import threading

CDatei = subprocess.Popen("/home/pi/meinc++/Spi")
print("Hallo")

i = 0
x = 0


def GetValue():
        with open("/home/pi/meinc++/BeispielDatei.txt","r") as Datei:
                for line in Datei:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    return line

def WithoutNull(input):
    ReturnValue = input
    while ReturnValue is None:
            ReturnValue = GetValue()
    return ReturnValue

def UebergabeWert():
    while x == 0:
        WholeString = WithoutNull(GetValue())
        StringVar, DatumVar = WholeString.strip().split(' - ')
        IntStringVar = [int(v) for v in StringVar.split()]
        return IntStringVar,DatumVar

def MinutenWert():
    ArrayValue = []
    ZeitStart = time.time()
    i = 0
    while 1:
        CompleteValue, Datum = UebergabeWert()
        ArrayValue.insert(i,CompleteValue[0])
        i = i + 1
        ZeitEnde = time.time()
        if (ZeitEnde-ZeitStart >= 10):
            LaengeArray = len(ArrayValue)
            print ArrayValue
            ArrayValue = []
            i = 0
            break


    while i <= LaengeArray:
        CompleteValue, Datum = UebergabeWert()
        ArrayValue.insert(i,CompleteValue[0])
        i = i + 1
        ArraySumme = numpy.sum(ArrayValue)
        LaengeArray = len(ArrayValue)
        Mittelwert = ArraySumme/LaengeArray
        print ArrayValue
        print ArraySumme
        print LaengeArray

        yield Mittelwert

        if i == LaengeArray:
            i = 0

xx = MinutenWert()
    for x in xx:
        print x
```

Quick Explanation of the Code:

I have a sensor and I'm reading data out of the UebergabeWert(). But since i wanted to make the average of a minute, i started to do following: I put the data in an array for 60 seconds (in the code it's 10 cause i dont want to wait so long) and then i sum up the array and divide it with the length of the array.

The first while loop is to set the total Array length (cause i cant make my main loop dependend from the time cause when the sensor is slower, it messes up with the data) and the second loop is to make the average. The idea is: when the array reaches it's end, it will erase the first value and insert the newest one. The loop should go indefinitely and I'll soon implement threading so it runs in the background.

PS: the "prints" are here for me to keep track of the process

My Problem:

The first loop works perfectly, the array prints out about 100 (different) values in the array without None.

The second loop however, breaks after the first iteration.

Error-message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 87, in <module>
    for x in xx:
  line 54, in MinutenWert
    CompleteValue, Datum = UebergabeWert()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Why is there suddenly a NoneType-error? I just cannot figure it out.

EDIT:
People pointed out that the problem is rather with a previous function of the code so I'll add it to the code.

Also, quick explanation: The data is in a textfile so i open the textfile with GetValue(). Sometimes the sensor is too slow and gives back a None-value so WithoutNull() gets rid of that.

The data is in this form "var1, var2, var3, var4 - timestamp". So i need to seperate the values from the String with UebergabeWert(). Normally i won't get a null-response from that so it's kinda strange.

Comment: The error message suggests that the function UebergabeWert() returns None instead of the expected tuple.

Comment: Okay, so it has nothing to do with MinutenWert() or yield?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. "CompleteValue, Datum = UebergabeWert()" is the line giving the error. It implicitly tries to unpack a tuple (a,b) returned by UebergabeWert(), but in this case the function returned None instead.

Comment: Please, add to your question code of function `UebergabeWert`

Comment: Done. Please also read the Edit at the End of my post.

Comment: Do you consistently get the same error on the same line?
Try replacing CompleteValue, Datum = UebergabeWert() with temp = UebergabeWert() and print temp

Comment: Yes the error is always on the same line. I tried that and like before it prints temp out once normally and then it crashes

Comment: When i get rid of the second (timestamp) variable, the error is on line 56 "ArrayValue.insert(i, CompleteValue[0])" with the Error "NoneType object has no attribute '__getitem__'" what's that?

Comment: The x which i print at the end prints None. Even though the yield value Mittelwert HAS a value

Comment: When i do it with "return" it says "numpy.int32 is not iterable"

Comment: Mittelwert is a single value, and therefore not iterable. 
The 'getitem' error just says that indexing ([0]) on None is not possible.

Comment: Alright. Programming is frustrating ^^ Do you know another way to return Mittelwert without stopping the loop (& def)?

Comment: Just to clarify... Are you just trying to get the average value of the sensor readout over the past minute?

Comment: @ThijisW Good News: Yes i am and i just noticed a major flaw in my code. In the second loop i defined LaengeArray = len(ArrayValue) which messes up the Mittelwert. I threw that line and  ArrayValue = [] out. Then i ran the code without yield just to see if the "prints" are valid. The results looked well so i thought it must be something with yield. I gathered some information from the Internet and voila. The mistake I made was to print x at the end. Yield called by the "next" statement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So i just replaced "for x in xx:  print x" with "while 1: next(xx) print(xx)"

Comment: Nice one. Feel free to write up what you found in an answer, and accept it.

Comment: I'll do that. Again, thank you for your help, without you pushing me in the right direction I wouldn't have found the source of the NoneType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with...

```
xx = MinutenWert()
    for x in xx:
        print x
```

It returns None because the Yield isn't called. To get Yield values one have to use next().

The updated version....

```
xx = Minutenwert()
while 1:
   y = next(xx)
   print y
```

returns the values and doesn't give back an error.